# P Value permutations in R

Tags: r, loops, permutation

I´m pretty new in r

I´m performing permutation test in R to determine if the percentage of ocurrence of some SNP is aleatory or not
My data set a vector of 52K values
Im doing the test via Loop as is:

```
R1_H <- R1[,12] #extract the vector from a dataframe

niter=100000       #set the number of iterations
out <- rep(0,length(R1_H))

for (i in 1:niter){
out = out + (R1_H <= sample(R1_H)) #compare my ocurrence against a 
                                 #sample of the entire population
}

pvalue=out/niter #determine the pvalue
R1$pvalueF = pvalue #print the pvalue
```

The problem is that this way is extremely slow and resource consuming.
Anybody think a more effective way to do it?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you are doing. But a few points. R has the `replicate` function built in that is designed explicitly for this kind of thing. One option you could use is:

```
my_vector <- replicate(niter, 
                   expr = (R1_H <= sample(R1_H, replace = T)))
```

Which will repeat the `expr` for `niter` times. In this case it will sample with replacement and return a matrix with the number of datapoints in R1_H and 10k columns. Then you could do something like:

```
mean(colMeans(my_vector))
```

To get the "pvalue" that you are trying to report.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
We want to determine  if the occurrence of a single observation (which is the number of "positive" occurrences in a population composed of 52K observations is aleatory or not. To do that, how many times the that "ocurrence" is bigger than an aleatory sample of the entire population. Thats our P Value. 
Your solution is interesting but it is generating a too big vector that cannot be allocated in my memory

Comment: I would check out <https://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/permutationtests.html> I think this might be the answer that you are looking for